# Unserialize an associtive array with iOS from a text string that was serialized with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, ios, objective-c, sqlite

I am building a web application that will parse my website's database to an xml file so that it can be uploaded to an iOS application.  I'm using MySQL for my website's database and using SQLite for the iOS app.  It seems pretty straight forward, except for some of the columns in the MySQL tables are text entries that were created by serializing associative arrays using php.

For example, an array would look like this:

```
(
   "images" => ("png" => 1, "jpg" => 1), 
   "videos" => ("mp4" => 3, "m4v" => 3)
)
```

After serializing the array with php - serialize($array); - The text file that is entered into the table entry looks like this:

```
a:2:{s:6:"images";a:2:{s:3:"png";i:1;s:3:"jpg";i:1;}s:6:"videos";a:2:{s:3:"mp4";i:3;s:3:"m4v";i:3;}}
```

For my website application I just use the php function unserialze($array); in order to use the array.

Is there a way to do this with iOS? Can iOS **unserialize** a string and create an NSDictionary object the same way PHP does with associative arrays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iOS does not provide a deserialization method for PHP's serialization format. Instead, you should use JSON as your serialization format. In PHP, you'd `json_encode()` and in Objective-C you'd use `NSJSONSerialization`.

Comment: I had a feeling that's what I was going to have to do.  Thanks for the quick answer!